# python numpy create dataset column: only add value based on condition otherwise null

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I try to create the column termination date. But only if the flag cancellations or lapses is set to yes the column termination date should contain the effective date, otherwise null. I receive the following error message for these three approaches.

```
df['Termination_Date'] = np.where((df['Cancellations'] == 'Yes') | (df['Lapses'] == 'Yes'), df['Effective Date'])
ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given

df['Termination_Date'] = np.where((df['Cancellations'] == 'Yes') | (df['Lapses'] == 'Yes'), df['Effective Date'], "")
TypeError: invalid type promotion

df['Termination_Date'] = np.where((df['Cancellations'] == 'Yes') | (df['Lapses'] == 'Yes'), df['Effective Date'], np.nan)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

thanks

Comment: What are the possible values for the `'Cancellations'` and `'Lapses'` column? Using magic strings instead of booleans is a terrible idea! In fact, what does the entire DatFrame look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is possible use alternative with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)?

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Effective Date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=6),
         'Cancellations':['Yes'] * 4 + ['No'] * 2,
         'Lapses':['yes'] * 2 + ['No'] * 4,

})

df['Termination_Date'] = df['Effective Date'].where((df['Cancellations'] == 'Yes') | 
                                                     (df['Lapses'] == 'Yes'))
```

Or:

```
m = (df['Cancellations'] == 'Yes') | (df['Lapses'] == 'Yes')
df.loc[m, 'Termination_Date'] = df['Effective Date']
```

---

```
print (df)
  Effective Date Cancellations Lapses Termination_Date
0     2019-01-01           Yes    yes       2019-01-01
1     2019-01-02           Yes    yes       2019-01-02
2     2019-01-03           Yes     No       2019-01-03
3     2019-01-04           Yes     No       2019-01-04
4     2019-01-05            No     No              NaT
5     2019-01-06            No     No              NaT
```

Comment: This is actually a great example of why it is far better to use booleans instead of a bunch of magic strings. `'Lapses':['yes'] * 2 + ['No'] * 4` should be `'Lapses':['Yes'] * 2 + ['No'] * 4`, right? Also, I would suggest putting the `.loc[]` solution first. It's more idiomatic Pandas, and `numpy.where()` shouldn't be used with just the single condition argument anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Termination_Date'] = df['Effective Date'].where( (df['Cancellations'] == 'Yes') |
                                                     (df['Lapses'] == 'Yes') )
```

or [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
df['Termination_Date'] = df['Effective Date'].mask( df['Cancellations'].ne('yes')
                                              .mul(df['Lapses'].ne('Yes') )
```

---

Also we can check with [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
df['Termination_Date'] = df['Effective Date'].where( df[['Lapses','Cancellations']].eq('Yes').any(axis = 1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .loc to index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Effective_Date':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods = 6),
               'Cancellations':['Yes'] * 4 + ['No'] * 2,
               'Lapses':['Yes'] * 2 + ['No'] * 4})

df
    Effective_Date  Cancellations   Lapses
0   2019-01-01      Yes             Yes
1   2019-01-02      Yes             Yes
2   2019-01-03      Yes             No
3   2019-01-04      Yes             No
4   2019-01-05      No              No
5   2019-01-06      No              No

df["Termination_Date"] = df.loc[(df["Cancellations"] == "Yes") | (df["Lapses"] == "Yes"), "Effective_Date"]

    Effective_Date  Cancellations   Lapses  Termination_Date
0   2019-01-01      Yes             Yes     2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02      Yes             Yes     2019-01-02
2   2019-01-03      Yes             No      2019-01-03
3   2019-01-04      Yes             No      2019-01-04
4   2019-01-05      No              No      NaT
5   2019-01-06      No              No      NaT
```